# Getting 404 from deployed WCF Service but can get service definition

Tags: azure, wcf

I have written a WCF Service. I can successfully run and debug it locally using the Visual Studio WCF Test Client and also a small Console application.

After publishing the service to Azure I can browse to the App Service Homepage and get the *"Hey, App Service developers!"* welcome page.

I can also browse to the `https://<mydeployment>.azurewebsites.net/<myservice>` and get the page that describes how to create a test app and get the service definition.

Finally, I can browse to the `https://<mydeployment>.azurewebsites.net/<myservice>?wsdl` and get the service description displayed as xml and create a test client from that.

**However** whenever I run the test client against the Azure deployment I get 404 responses. I can see those same 404 responses logged in the Azure log streams.

Any suggestions of why I'm getting 404's or how I can troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 0):

Which way you use to call the service, what is the service endpoint address? I suspect there is something error in the service address. Service endpoint address is relative to the service base address.
For example, there is the below definition.

```
<service name="Server4.Calculator">
        <endpoint address="service" binding="customBinding" contract="Server4.ICalculator" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
```

The service address on the client-side should be IIS base address and the service relative address.
https://192.168.1.100:8000/service1.svc/service
Generally speaking,  if the service description is available, we could generate the client proxy class by adding service reference, the service endpoint will be set up in the configuration file.
[image]
Then we could use the client proxy class to call the service.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            var result = client.Test();
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.